# Total de vendas por mês agrupado por vendedor

Tags: sql

Estou precisando trazer uma listagem de executivos e total de suas vendas por mês, isso tudo independente de ter venda no mês ou não.

Faz anos que estou focado em front-end e nunca mais tinha feito algo com sql, podem me ajudar?

```
vendedor   janeiro fevereiro marco abril maio junho julho agosto ...

vendedor1  300     400       800   0     0    0     0     0
vendedor2  100     50        30    0     100  50    0     0
```

Comment: você pode pesquisar por `unpivot` e `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde! Por favor, me informe se o código funcionar corretamente. obrigado.

```
SELECT 
sum(janeiro) AS total_jan,
sum(fevereiro) AS total_fev,
sum(marco) AS total_mar,
sum(abril) AS total_abr,
sum(maio) AS total_mai,
sum(junho) AS total_jun,
sum(julho) AS total_jul,
sum(agosto) AS total_ago,
sum(setembro) AS total_set,
sum(outubro) AS total_out,
sum(novembro) AS total_nov,
sum(dezembro) AS total_dez
FROM nome_da_tabela
GROUP BY vendedor;
```

Comment: Ontem mesmo, sentei com calma, abri uma cerveja e apaguei tudo para pensar melhor e deu certo, sim ficou no mesmo estilo do seu código.

Fico muito agradecido pela resposta.

Comment: 100sacional ! fico feliz que tenha funcionado! tamo junto ;)